# Facebook Graph API - Getting a list of your friends friends?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the ruby on rails gem koala to access the facebook graph API.

What I want to be able to do if make a call to get a list of my friends friends.

I'm trying that with:

```
fb_connections = @graph.get_connections(fb_uid, 'friends').to_json
```

where fb_uid is a friends uid, but that is not working. It's only sending back friends for my account not my friends. Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: I know this post is really old, but were you ever able to find a way to access your friends friends?

Answer (score 2):

If user is logged in with omniauth, you get the token, and you can use that token to call
    https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=AAAD46kEqljsBAKQEbJ2mU6seZCLunsCbT0zmGNc....

and get the friendlist in JSON format

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Andrew Rude",
         "id": "500111111"
      },
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

From a technology standpoint, you can only request information about yourself, so YOUR education and YOUR friends.

It also makes sense from a business standpoint... If you could just ask facebook for everybody's friends, then the social graph would cease being facebook's. it'd be yours.

Also: your friend hasn't given your (some random app) clearance to their information, so that's another reason you can't get it without their consent.